# Datastage Server Job V8.5 OracleDB Date Not Loading Properly

Tags: database, oracle, load, datastage

DataStage® Release: 8x
Job Type: Server
OS: Windows
Additional info: Datastage Server Job V8.5

Here is a peculiar error.

In a datastage server job,

My source data from a sequential file has date field with following value
yyyymmdd

Date
20121017

I am loading into oracle DB however that column in the database shows up as '21-JUN-57' (This is 06/21/7057)

I am not doing any transformations on the date. It is straight mapping.

I want the target in format 17-OCT-2012

The source data from sequential file has date as SQL Type and target has the same SQL Type. The Oracle DB matches perfectly in terms of column name, data type.

Can you please shed some light on why the date is not loading correctly and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the input as Varchar(8) and then in a transformer stage make StringToDate(in.yourDate,"%dd-%mmm-%yyyy")

Comment: this is datastage server job. What you have up there is a function available in parallel jobs only.  ANY OTHER SUGGESITONS ANYBODY???

Comment: You are loading a number into a target date field in the database? This is likely to make an error. Instead, you can use a Working Table with the Fields set with a VarChar/Char datatype and from this working table perform the insert into the target table with the proper transformations using the AFTER SQL script parameter in the Oracle Enterprise stage in Server. Check it and see if this works...